Book series about three boys and a girl who can traverse to different worlds with some kind of mission
I'm looking for a series that I read in middle school about three boys and a girl who can traverse to different worlds with some kind of mission.
I think the main guy in the first book had a red scarf that (if I remember correctly) was burned in the end in his fireplace. The plot follows the line of some sort of mission assigned to the kids. One of the boys is Japanese. The main character sort of "dies" in the last book.
I read these books around 5-6 years ago. The missions might have to do with preventing the collapse or destruction or the worlds? Some other points are that the Asian kid's parent died in a fire that was set upon their house and he was taken in by an older guy that brought the kids together. The older guy I think passes away at some point and the MC takes his place in the last book.
All of the books had some sort of illustration in a detailed pencil drawn style.

In roughly which year/s did you read these books? And what did the mission/s involve?

I read these books around 5-6 years ago. The misisons might have to do with preventing the collpase or destruction or the worlds? Some other points are that the aisan kids parent died in a fire that was set upon their house and he was taken in by an older guy that brought the kids together. The older guy I think passes away at some point and the mc takes his place in the last book. Sorry if some of this is vague.

When you say "different worlds," are you talking about alien planets, or alternate Earths/parallel universes?

Pretty sure it's alien like planets. Talking animals etc.
